# Populating UI with info from tableview cell? - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

Hi I have tried to follow tutorials online but can't seem to get it working.

I am trying to populate a view controller with information from the pressed cell from a table view ... it picks up which cell has been selected but then opens the view controller twice... it also doesn't populate the ui label?

Please advise thank you.

**Table View Class where user selects a cell ;**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell

        title = currentCell.textLabel?.text
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "passInfoSegue", sender: self)
    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

        if (segue.identifier == "passInfoSegue") {
            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
            let viewController = segue.destination as! NextViewController
            // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
            viewController.passedValue = title!
        }
    }
```

**Next View Controller ;**

```
class NextViewController : UIViewController{

    var passedValue : String!

    @IBOutlet weak var featLabel: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descripLabel: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ampImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        featLabel.text = passedValue
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that you connected the segue in Interface Builder from the call to the next viewcontroller. Connect from first vc to next vc.

Comment: that solves one problem thank you! can you help me out with why its not populating my ui correctly? Thank you! @Larme

Comment: Check in `viewDidLoad()` `passedValue`. Check if you don't set somewhere else `featLabel.text`.

Comment: its nil when clicked so must be the code from the table view class? @Larme

Comment: Indeed. Check `title = currentCell.textLabel?.text`, or when you do `viewController.passedValue = title!`.

Comment: just debugged best I could and found it docent enter the prepforsegue function hence why nothings been passed, do you know why this is? Thanks for the help @Larme

Comment: `func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` I think that's not a Swift 3 (or Swift 4) version of that. Remove it and let XCode suggest you the correct method signature/name, or search it in the doc. Should be `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` You took that method signature/name from an old Swift tutorial.

Comment: yes it wasnt the right function thank you! but now it picks up the title where title = currentCell.textLabel?.text but then when it reaches the prepforseg it says title is nil ..... @Larme

Comment: Why don't you do `title = myArrayThatPopulatedMyTableView...[indexPath.row]` (the "..." depends in your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`) or something like that?

Comment: @Larme thank you its passing it over now!!! thank you so much